# How can i check the mysql server is installed or not before installing the application in Inno setup compiler

Tags: inno-setup

I need inno setup compiler script to check whether mysql server is installed or not before installing the application.

Comment: That's hard to determine. MySQL doesn't always need to be installed. You can download a ZIP archive and from time to time just run the required service. Would you force the installation of your MySQL version in this case ? I wouldn't do so.

Comment: i am creating an application package by using inno setup compiler. This application uses mysql as database. So during installation of this package it should prompt to install mysql

Comment: I can imagine what you're developing; I'm following InnoSetup tag for some time ;-) With my previous comment I was just going to tell, that the MySQL detection is not reliable and you should not install MySQL automatically by what you determine. If MySQL would not be found, ask the user. That sounds fair.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL is quit differ than other ones, we can also use MySQL with out installing into our system by running required services time to time from the downloaded zip archives, extracted files may be placed any where on the system...Tlama Already mentioned this.

Here we have two cases to Check

**Case 1:-MySQL is installed or not**

**Direxists** function(Here you can Check whether  MySQL  directory exists in program files or not )
MySQL directory path :**{pf}\MySQL**

**Filexists** function(with this you can check  required MySQL  files are there in the users systems )

**Query the registry** with the MySQL registry Key names

HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1707045092-1792370289-147592793-1000\Software\MySQL
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1707045092-1792370289-147592793-1000\Software\MySQL AB
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MySQL
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MySQL AB
check whether these are existed in registry or not.

if Every thing is existed, that's fine. Go for your application installation

if no check for case 2 also

**Case 2:- Is there any files or directories with the name of MySQL in the entire system and required services of Mysql are running or not**

a. first check whether is there any file or folder exists with the name of MySQL in the users machine by using below commands, to execute commands you can use **Exec** function

with the below one you can find whether MySQL(file/directory)  is there in c drive or not,  but not in entire system

```
C:\>tree |find "mysql" >filename
```

b)now change the drive to D,E,F by using

below command will give you , all disk drives in the machine

```
C:\>wmic logicaldisk get caption >filename
```

then check each and every drive in the above filename

```
 C:\>D:  
 d:\>tree |find "mysql" >filename
```

each time **Loadstringfromfile** to some string and then check the length of string is zero or not.
if not zero, you need to check for required services are running or not by using (you can skip some above steps for simplicity)

```
tasklist |find "required service of MySQL" >filename
```

if all drives finished and if did not found any thing, no worries simply prompt user to download MySQL ([Use ITD(Innoo tools downloader)](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=50)) or else you can pack MySQL msi with your application but your application become bulky(Contains more memory).

Comment: Thank you Gangadhar, from last day onward i am trying with your logic.  i am checking only registry entry, for checking it need to have a registry key, I can check the Version by using : 

RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.5', 'Version', Retval); 

here i can check only version 5.5, if its version 5.6, i need to change that registry path to 
'SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.6'

Plz help me to how can i read a common path value? is it possible?

Comment: you can export registry values to a file by using regedit.exe with export to file option. if you want to export registry values of **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MySQL AB** registry key,   use   **params:='/e "C:\Myfile.txt" HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MySQL AB';**                                                            **Exec('regedit',params, '', SW_SHOW,ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);**                                                  After then use **Loadstringsfromfile('C:\Myfile.txt',regstrings)** here regstrings:Tarrayofstring variable,finally use the info in the regstrings.

Comment: if you get any problem with the space in between MySQL and AB use double quotes **"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MySQL AB"**

Comment: Hi  Gangadhar, 
instead of going to download link, how can i call mysqlsetup exe file by allocate mysql application with main exe.