# How to check if Crystal Reports Runtime Environment for Visual Studio 2008 is installed in my system

Tags: crystal-reports, inno-setup, crystal-reports-2008

I need to check if Crystal reports runtime environment(32/64 bit) is installed in my system using inno setup. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can check **any thing installed or not** with inno setup by using different ways

you can find Crystal reports runtime environment(32/64 bit) is installed or not,
**By querying registry** or **By checking for existence of directories** or  **By checking for existence of files** of that particular installer.

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669678/how-can-i-check-the-mysql-server-is-installed-or-not-before-installing-the-appli) will help you to find the way. Here I was explained how to check MySQL is installed or not, Apply same for Crystal reports runtime environment(32/64 bit).

Answer (score 0):

For x86, look for this folder :

C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86

For x64, look for this folder :

C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64